# Where should I sort and filter? back-end or front-end?

Tags: django, reactjs, graphql

I am running into a conceptual conflict on whether I should sort and filter on frontend or backend.

Some suggested the logic should be at backend and limited number of data ie) 10-100 results at a time should be provided to the client if you have like millions of data set to reduce the page load time. What I am confused is, what if there are many clients sorting and filtering concurrently (ie 100 users) If this is the case, then you are having to sort and filter millions of records 100 times, constantly, which I think will slow down the server.

If I assume that my data set is around 10000 - 100000 and I have 10-50 users using the app concurrently, and if initial time load doesn't matter so much as it would be a private enterprise app ie) ERP, where should filter and sort logic live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one right answer to your question, following are pros and cons for your question.

Sorting at server end:

1. Server overhead by sorting the data.
2. Less data transfer for the user since you are already sending filtered data.
3. User experience might be bad if sorting take lots of time, user would be waiting with a blank screen.

Sorting at user end:

1. Increased network usage for both server and the user, hence long running process for the server.
2. Might give slightly better user experience, it might increase the overall increase in page load time but user would have some data on his screen.

Best would be to user best of the both world, rather than sticking to one.

You can use caching at server level, that may increase your application performance.

Comment: How would you use best of the both world? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Storing frequently queried data in sorted form, if data set is very small then process it at consumer end.